# How to get Log file from running a cmd file

Tags: logging, cmd, command-line

I have a nugetrestore.cmd file. And when running the cmd file, I want the log file. How Can achieve this ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to make any changes to your batch file when you run it from a Command Prompt window; ```nugetrestore.cmd 1>"MSBuildLogs.log" 2>&1```.

Answer (score 0):

Added this line of code. Able to get the logs now.

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=MSBuildLogs.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
:LOG
```

Comment: The snippet you have posted will run the code within `:LOG` twice!